# jsTree removes text from <li> tags

Tags: jstree

I am trying jsTree for the first time, and have the problem that after calling `jstree()`, the text in my `<li>` elements vanishes. After the call, my tree looks like this:

```
<div id="assessment-treeview" class="jstree jstree-0 jstree-focused jstree-classic">
    <ul>
        <li class="jstree-last jstree-open"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
            <ul style="">
                <li class="jstree-last jstree-open"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>
                    <ul style="">
                        <li class="jstree-last jstree-leaf"><ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Before the call it looks like this:

```
<div id="assessment-treeview">
    <ul>
        <li>Specific Outcomes
            <ul>
                <li>[section: name not available for import]
                    <ul>
                        <li>[outcome: name not available for import] </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The jstree call looks like this:

```
$("#assessment-treeview").jstree({ "themes": { "theme": "classic" } });
```

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jsTree doesn't like pure text nodes inside the 'li' tag. When I put the item text into a tag like 'span', everything worked fine again.

From the question code above:

```
<li><span>Specific Outcomes</span>
    <ul>
    .        
    .       
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Wow, they should at least bother to make the examples in the official site right, because they use raw text inside li tags as if it would work. Thanks for the answer.